# changing the after_commit callback execution order for related classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions, activesupport

I have two classes A & B. B is having `belongs_to` relationship with A:

```
B {
     relationships:{
        A  {type: :belongs_to}
     }
}
```

I'm using active record `after_commit` callbacks in the models of both A & B, something like below:

```
A {
     after_commit -> { commit_to_kafka_for_a }, :on => :create
}

B {
     relationships:{
        A  {type: :belongs_to}
     }
     after_commit -> { commit_to_kafka_for_b }, :on => :create
}
```

When I run both of these in a Transaction:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

  a_obj = A.new
  B.a_obj = a_obj
  B.save!

end
```

In the transaction steps, A is the first object that is created.
The `after_commit` of B (which is a child entity) is called first. , i.e sequence of callbacks execution:

```
 1. commit_to_kafka_for_b
 2. commit_to_kafka_for_a
```

Is there any way I can call the `after_commit` of parent class A first, then the child class (B). A sequence like:

```
 1. commit_to_kafka_for_a
 2. commit_to_kafka_for_b
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: does it matter if its after_create callbacks and not after_commit - does it still behave the same way?